# Magento 2.2.5: How to get product id after product saved using plugin

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, plugin, save

I'm looking for how to get product id after product saved using plugin.
I use the plugin to catch after execute() is fired.
But I can't get product id no matter how I try.
Here is what I've done:

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save">
        <plugin name="synergy_butility_save_product"
                type="Synergy\Butility\Plugin\Product\Save"
        />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Synergy\Butility\Plugin\Product;

class Save
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save $subject, $result)
    {
        // AB-18 -fudu- update news_to_day take data from news_to_date in catalog_product_flat_32 table after "saved product" in admin page
        $productId = $subject->productId;

        $post = $this->_request->getPost();
        var_dump($post); exit;
        // $news_to_date = $subject->getProduct()->getNewsToDate();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_flat_32');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE entity_id = " . $productId;

        $product = $connection->query($query);

        foreach ($product as $rows) {
            var_dump($rows);
        }
        var_dump('doesnt work');
        exit;
        $update_to_db = "UPDATE " . $tableName . " SET news_to_day = '" . $news_to_date . "'  WHERE entity_id = " . $productId;
        $connection->query($update_to_db);
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if your question not solve.

Comment: Is it working? @Fudu

Comment: please check my answer :) thanks for replying

Comment: In plugin , did you check $this->_request->getParams(); and print that? You can also find product id from there.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: hmm .. i have some answer for my issue, thanks you for replying :)

Comment: okay please accept and upvote answer if it's useful for you . So, other can use this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **product object** after saving product from backend then you can easily use `catalog_product_save_after` event.

Put this **events.xml** in below path `app\code\vendor_name\module_name\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="vendor_name\module_name\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And put your **Productsaveafter.php** in below path `app\code\vendor_name\module_name\Observer\`

```
<?php

namespace vendor_name\module_name\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $product_id = $_product->getId(); // for product id
        $product_sku = $_product->getSku(); // for sku
    }   
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

If you want to get in plugin. Then, you can get by below line.

```
$product_id = $this->_request->getParam('id');
```

Comment: sorry but i want to use plugin, not observer. :( and i already have the answer, but for some reason, it deleted by admin of magento.stackexchange :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a plugin, have you tried doing this with event e.g. catalog_product_save_after?

It works on both 'update' and 'create' e.g.

1) In file `\app\code\Testspace\Test\etc\adminhtml\events.xml` define:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="price" instance="Testspace\Test\Model\Observer\Save" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then in your observer

```
namespace Testspace\Test\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class Save implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($observer->getProduct()->getId()); echo '</pre>';
        die();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried use observer but it only worked for "update product", not with "add product" @@

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution based on this link
https://webkul.com/blog/mass-update-products-attribute-magento-2/

So basically if you follow this solution, you don't need to use query in observer anymore

Here is how i did:

> ProductSaveObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Synergy\Butility\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // AB-18 update news_to_day take data from news_to_date in catalog_product_flat_32 table after "saved product" in admin page
        $productId = $observer->getProduct()->getId();

        $productIdArr = [$productId];

        $news_to_date = $observer->getProduct()->getNewsToDate();
        $news_to_date = substr($news_to_date,0,-8);
        $news_to_date = $news_to_date.'00:00:00';

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $productActionObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action');
        $productActionObject->updateAttributes($productIdArr, array('news_to_day' => $news_to_date), 0);
    }
}
```