# Unable to get newly inserted Product's Id using After Plugin for Catalog Product save controller method

Tags: product, controllers, magento2.3, interceptor, after-plugin

I have created interceptor for catalog product controller's save action

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save">
    <plugin name="ricky_catalog_save_product"
            type="Ricky\Catalog\Plugin\Product\Save" sortOrder="10"
    />
</type>
```

My plugin class is below

```
namespace Ricky\Catalog\Plugin\Product; 

class Save {
     public function afterExecute(
          \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save $subject,
           $result)
    {
         $productId = $subject->productId; // This is not working
         /**
         echo $result->getProduct->getId(); die("prodid");
         echo $subject->getProduct->getId(); die("prodid");
         Both throw exception: Undefined property $getProduct
        **/

         /** $productId is provided in excute method in Save class 
            in Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save **/
    }
}
```

**For some reasons I have to use Plugin** (Interceptor Design Pattern), I know I can get newly created prouduct id by using observer for catalog_product_save_after event. But please provide solution for plugins.

I am asking this after visiting [This Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246925/magento-2-2-5-how-to-get-product-id-after-product-saved-using-plugin)

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Try this $subject->getProduct->getId(); @KapilDevSingh

Comment: I tried this, but its throws exception `Undefined property: Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor::$getProduct`
well thanks for response @PrathapGunasekaran

Comment: use $result variable .

Comment: Thankyou for reply @AnandOntigeri,  I have tried this one also but this also throws same exception.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran , This also not worked, even it ended with FATAL ERROR
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect\Interceptor::getAllItems()

Comment: @KapilDevSingh these will not work as function is not returning the instance of product , but a instance of RedirectFactory https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c36f6f237a3b83d6acd8b87c979e73fd8ffbfea/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php#L102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$product` is not accessible from outside the `save` method. The only exceptioon is the event `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after`.
But the product builder puts the product into registry, so you may access the product from there.
This code should work in my opinion, but I didn't test it:

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
      \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save $subject,
       $result)
    {
        //get the product from registry
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        $productId = $product->getId();

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: You didn't tested but I applied, It works like a charm. ThankYou.
So basically if we want to pass variables from save **(Controller)** to outside then we can use registry.

Comment: @helgeb Registry is deprecated in magento 2.3, Should not be used https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c36f6f237a3b83d6acd8b87c979e73fd8ffbfea/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Registry.php#L8-L18

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar yes, I know, but it is the only way I see to access the product using a plugin. I would rather use the event but the question was about the plugin usage